# Базовые типы в Java

Tags: java

В [лекции Шипилева](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB2N8aqwtxc) есть замечание о том, что в `java` из базовых типов есть 8 примитивов типов и ссылка(8:30).Но ведь ссылка - это один из классов пакета `java.lang.ref`, разве нет ? И если, например,  `WeekReference` - это базовый тип, то почему `Object` таким не является ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, ссылка в том контексте - это обычная ссылка (не класс из какого-либо пакета). Например,

```
List list = new ArrayList(); // ссылка link на экземпляр класса ArrayList
Object o = new Object(); // ссылка o на экземпляр класса Object 
// ... и т.д.
```

Это замечание про синтаксис языка. Устройство JVM может отличаться. JVM (например, HotSpot) может быть с применением shared_ptr из С++. Тогда отличия между обычной ссылкой и ссылкой из пакета `java.lang.ref` почти не будет - на этапе перевода байт-кода в нативный код они будут заменены на shared_ptr и unique_ptr с разными счетчиками.

Comment: А эту ссылку можно как-нибудь "потрогать" ? Прочитать адрес из нее как `C++` или что-нибудь такое.

Comment: @faoxis, можно прочитать адрес через Unsafe - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820369/6672928